# Visual Studio 2017 shuts down after updating database from solution explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

This problem is occurred today when I was working on a project. When I made some changes in database table design and tried to update the database by clicking on update button and then immediately VS restarted automatically. Then again I did the same thing 3 or 4 times but the problem still remained.
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried the standard reboot and/or reinstall visual studio?

Comment: Please provide a little bit more context. Which version of VS do you use? (latest 15.8.6)  
May you provide a screenshot of what you are doing exactly?  
You can search https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com for current issues and submit one there too